# Could not locate ring/util/request__init.class or ring/util/request.clj on classpath

Tags: clojure, leiningen, ring

```
FileNotFoundException 
Could not locate ring/util/request__init.class or ring/util/request.clj on classpath:   
clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
```

This is happening in the leiningen repl when i try to use one my namespaces:

```
(use 'cmp.repl)
```

This issue is only happening on my deployment environment (Ubuntu Server 12) but it works fine on my development environment Mac OS 10.8

My project.clj file is as follows:

```
(defproject cmp "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"

:license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [lib-noir "0.5.0"]
                 [compojure "1.1.5"]
                 [com.cemerick/friend "0.1.5" :exclusions [ring/ring-core]]
                 [ring-server "0.2.7"]
                 [clabango "0.5"]
                 [korma "0.3.0-RC5"]
                 [clj-json "0.5.3"] 
                 [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.6"]
                 [com.taoensso/timbre "1.5.2"]
                 [com.taoensso/tower "1.5.1"]
                 [com.postspectacular/rotor "0.1.0"]
                 [markdown-clj "0.9.19"]
                 [clj-pdf "1.11.1"]
                 [dk.ative/docjure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.1"]
                 [clj-time "0.6.0"]
                 [log4j "1.2.15"
                  :exclusions
                  [javax.mail/mail
                   javax.jms/jms
                   com.sun.jdmk/jmxtools
                   com.sun.jmx/jmxri]]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.7"]]
  :ring {:handler cmp.handler/war-handler
         :init    cmp.handler/init
         :destroy cmp.handler/destroy}
  :profiles
  {:production {:ring {:open-browser? false
                       :stacktraces?  false
                       :auto-reload?  false}}
   :dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.3"]
                        [ring/ring-devel "1.1.8"]]}}
  :java-source-paths ["src/cmp/java"]
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running **lein deps :tree** i found that i had to add an exclusion for **ring/ring-core** to compojure in the project file as well. Working well for me now